# Option-N and Option-P (What are they doing and how do I disable or rebind them?)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, emacs, logic

On Catalina 10.15.6 (and even on High Sierra), typing either **Option-N** or **Option-P** pops up a series of "quick looks" at all my current "application windows." But I am unable to find any documentation about what this is called (it only appeared in 10.14, I believe).

I have spent--truly--hours looking up how to understand and change this behavior...shocked this is not mentioned anywhere.

While I can see some value in this behavior, I use those keys in Emacs (as well as Logic Pro), where N/P keys are frequently used as mnemonics for "next/previous." While I have worked around this in Emacs by using ESC as a substitue, I want to free up Option-N and Option-P again.

If I can learn the name of this operation, I will gladly also rebind those functions to non-conflicting shortcuts.

Comment: Have you tried System Preferences->Keyboard shortcuts tab? Those key combinations do nothing on my Catalina Macs and are not listed here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Comment: I'm guessing you have "Application Windows" & maybe Mission Control itself set to that, in System Preferences->Keyboard > Mission Control. That's the only thing I can think of that might be considered 'quicklook' without actually being QuickLook itself.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks--the comments made me realize that I was barking up the wrong tree.

This shortcut was *not* a system shortcut but actually provided by Hammerspoon, specifically a feature (not a bug) of https://github.com/agzam/spacehammer, which is designed to provide convenient shortcuts for an "Spacemacs" workflow:

> ### Other features
>
> - Alternative App Switcher `Option n/p`
> - Simple tab switcher for Chrome and iTerm `Option j/k`

Quitting the whole Hammerspoon process gave me back those keys.